# xamarin forms Android App crashes when BroadcastReceiver fires during Doze in OREO

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, wakelock

I have a reminder app which needs to show reminders on time even if the phone is in Doze mode. This was appeared to be fine when compiling using the Android 7.1 SDK. 
My BroadcastReceiver gets a WAKE_LOCK when it starts and releases it in a finally clause. It also logs activity to a local SQLLite database (for debug) 
I've now changed to compile with Android 8.1 SDK and still all works fine 
when the phone is not in Doze mode.
However, when the phone goes into Doze the App crashes at the due time of the alarm. My logging statement, which is the first line within OnReceive, is not invoked.
I have traps in for uncaught exceptions, which report to AppCenter and record locally. These work for other exceptions.

```
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += ReportUnobservedTaskException;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += ReportUnhandledException;
        AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += ReportThrowableEvent;
```

Can anybody advise why and where this might be failing, or how I can debug it better?
It feels like a change since moving the 8.1 SDK for compiling, but I can't see anything that has changed that would affect this.

Comment: What is reported in `logcat`?

Comment: I'm new to Android dev and haven't done this on a Device yet. I will google how and get back to you.

Comment: OK - didn't realise the DeviceLog in Visual Studio shows events that occurred when the device was not connected (dumb, I know).

Comment: Looks like it is the act of writing to the log database which is causing the problem - presumably because I don't yet have the wake lock! Kind of the Observer effect. I will rebuild later today with these logging statements and report back what happens. Thanks for your help

Comment: NP, Post an update to your question if needed when you get to it...

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case it helps somebody else.

Investigation of the logcat shows that the problem here was that the application was not initialized when the Broadcast Receiver was invoked.

logcat showed the message:
    android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.InvalidOperationException: You MUST call 
    Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it.

It appears that a scheduled job was crashing the app and so when the alarm fired the receiver was not initialized and could not deal with the message.

Next investigation is why the scheduled job failed ....